# Click event on vue component that was pass down to slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have this two components part of my custom slider plugin, **component 1** will be the wrapper and the **component 2** will pass down to **component 1** slot:

`comp1.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div id="sliderwrapper">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

`comp2.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="slider">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now, in my Vue app, I do

```
<sliderwrapper>
    <sliderbox @click="slideritem(item.title)" v-for="(item,index) in slideritems" :key="index">
        <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
    </sliderbox>
</sliderwrapper>

import sliderwrapper from './comp1.vue';
import sliderbox from './comp2.vue';

export default{
    components : [ sliderwrapper, sliderbox ],
    data() {
        return {
            slideritems : [
                { title : 'title 1' },
                { title : 'title 2' },
                { title : 'title 3' },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods : {
        slideritem(title){
            alert(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the click event on component 2 `<sliderbox>` is not working nor triggering, something like event was not attached.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `sliderbox` component emit a `click` event? If not then you'll need to use `@click.native` to listen for the native DOM event.

Comment: @skirtle can you post an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Using `@click` on a component will only listen for a `click` event explicitly emitted by that component using `$emit`. It won't listen for the DOM event.

To listen for the native event you'd need to use `@click.native` instead.

See:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 1):

```
v-on:click.native="slideritem(item.title)"
```

should do it.